# Microsoft query Excel from SQLExpress nchar not returning

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an excell, there is a Data Connection to A SQLExpress DB, it works for all the data but not for an Nchar Field, it is always empty, when i check on management studio the data is there, but nothing return to excell or to Microsoft Query

here it says [Excel SSIS query returns null columns in Excel but not in Management studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365500/excel-ssis-query-returns-null-columns-in-excel-but-not-in-management-studio)   it should Work but not for me

Comment: Have you tried Power Query?. It comes with Excel 2016 and you can install it on excel 2010+ from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

Comment: I assume you aren't using an `n(var)char(MAX)`?

Comment: It could be a unicode decoding bug. Try converting nchar to say varchar and see if that works, then nchar to nvarchar